# How to create dynamic array in OpenCL?

Tags: c, opencl

I need to run kernel function 1 million times. In each core i need to create dynamic array of 1000 elements. How i can resolve this problem? Should i create buffer of 1 million * 1000 elements and contact them using id,but it's a lot of memory, and i haven't as much? Or is there another resolve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you have to create a buffer of 1mil*1000, at least thats what i experienced.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i will do so